# How to organize data after using filter

Tags: python, django, database

Let's say I have a database table like this:

```
NumCOL    NameCol    AgeCOL    ColourCOL
----------------------------------------
1         Joel       18         Blue
2         Joey       22         Red
3         Jacob      25         Green
4         Jack       27         Blue
5         Joey       21         Red
```

In this example, `NumCOL` is unique and icrements by 1, `NameCOL, AgeCOL & ColourCOL` are not unique. I need to filter them in a way that I can grab all entries based on `ColourCOL`, and then  grab   the entries in `NameCOL & AgeCOL`that are assiocated to the colour. I use this code below (where a user selects the colour blue):

```
colour = request.POST.get('FormColour') #colour = blue 
name = Database.objects.filter(ColourCOL=colour).values_list('NameCOL', flat=True)
```

Now there two names that have the colour blue, so I was thinking to use  a list and append all the data into a list and just call from the list when needs be, like this:

```
ex_list = []
tracker = 0
for x in name:
    age = Database.objects.filter(ColourCOL=colour, NameCOL=name).values_list('AgeCOL', flat=True)
    ex_list.append([name[tracker], name, age])
    tracker += 1
```

My concern is that I won't be able to retrieve data from the list effectively (if at all) if I need to write to a PDF or display it in a table. Another solution is sorting by the `NumCOL` but users only have access to the data in the `ColourCOL`. So what is the best way to sort all the information where I can display the colour selected, and then the name and age of everyone assicoated with that colour?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
colour = request.POST.get('FormColour') #colour = blue 
data_dict = Database.objects.filter(ColourCOL=colour).values('NameCOL', 'AgeCOL', 'NumCOL')
for data in data_dict:
    print(data['NameCOL'], data['AgeCOL'], data['NumCOL'])
```

You can create a dict out of the retrieved data using values, iterate over it and access the column name from dict.

Comment: thanks that worked! Now let's say I just need the price from `data_dict[0]` how would I retrieve it?

Comment: add price in values and access it using data_dict[0]['price']

Comment: You can access prefetched data using values and values_list.